# Problems with HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell

Tags: windows, registry, raku

I am try to send the name of a/any directory in Windows Explorer's Left column using the context menu to a program I wrote in Raku.

I have written the following to the registry

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\OpenWithFileAttributes.pl6\command]
@="\"C:\\rakudo\\bin\\raku.exe\" \"K:\\Windows\\NtUtil\\FileAttributes.pl6\" \"%V\""
```

Copied from the key itself it looks like:

```
"C:\rakudo\bin\raku.exe" "K:\Windows\NtUtil\FileAttributes.pl6" "%V"
```

When I right click on a directory in the left column, and left click on FileAttributes.pl6, it starts Raku in a shell, but does nothing else.  It does not start FileAttrebes.pl6 (or -v or -V or -?).

How do I tell the registry to send the parameters to Raku?

Many thanks,
-T

p.s. I already have folders and files from the right pane working

Comment: What is `OpenWithFileAttributes.pl6` ?

Comment: It tells you the attributes of a file or directory.  It basically wraps `C:\Windows\System32\fsutil.exe usn readdata` with msg pop ups and formatting.

Comment: Why is your registry value multiple strings? Or to put it another way, does it work if you combine all three strings into one, and if not, why not?

Comment: I have tried it without the quotes and it makes no difference.  The quotes are there to catch spaces in values and path names.  This work for the right pane: `; Any file, right or left panel
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\OpenWithFileAttributes.pl6\command]
@="\"C:\\rakudo\\bin\\raku.exe\" \"K:\\Windows\\NtUtil\\FileAttributes.pl6\" \"%1\""
`

Comment: the problem is that raku is not getting the rest of the run string

Comment: "it makes no difference." Then please get rid of them. Likewise any other unnecessary elements. For example, why is "%V" included in your question? Please (re)read and (re)apply the guidance provided in [MRE]. I understand that your goal is to pass a directory name to a script, but you're not even succeeding at getting the script passed to raku. While it makes sense to mention your overall goal it is extremely important to focus on one problem at a time per SO question.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this on Windows 10, Rakudo version 2020.01.

First I created a test script `C:\Users\hakon\raku\test.raku`:

```
use v6;
say "Hello world!";
say "Arguments:";
say "'$_'" for @*ARGS;
sleep 5;
```

Then I opened `regedit.exe` and added the key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\OpenWithRaku\command
```

I set the value of the latter `command` key to

```
C:\rakudo\bin\raku.exe C:\Users\hakon\raku\test.raku 1 2 3 "%V"
```

[image]

---

Then, I opened a new File Explorer window, and selected a folder from the left pane, and then right clicked on an empty space under the directory listing in the right pane, I then chose "OpenWithRaku" from the context menu.

[image]

---

After that a terminal window opened with the following output:

```
Hello world!
Arguments:
'1'
'2'
'3'
'C:\Users\hakon\raku'
```

So it seems to work fine on my machine.

Comment: No symptom change with your version.  rats!  1) did you right click on a directory in the "left" pane?  2) what version and build of Windows are you using `<win><R>WinVer`?  3) what does %V show when you are clicking on an actual directory, not a favorite shortcut?

Comment: Oh now get this!  It works in Windows 7.   And both are on Raku 2020.01.   AAAAHHHHH  !!!!!!

Comment: And I used the same .reg file (it is on a network drive) to registry both

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it is a bug in Widnows 10-1909.  There is no such issue with Windows 7